# Visual basic 6 - Export to Excel 2010/2013 not working

Tags: windows-7, vb6, excel-2013

I am stuck with this issue and need your help.

We have one **VB6** application that reads an **Excel** file (basically like a template) and writes data into specific cells finally exports it to a xls.

**The problem** is that the excel sheet is not opening in **office 2013** version. When I open the file, everything is blank. But the file size indicates that data got written into it. Moreover , the document is opening in Google docs but not in office 2013 version.

Below please find my code for it. (actual code is too long therefor can't paste it here).

```
   Set xlApp = Excel.Application
   Set xlBook = GetObject("file.xls")
   Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
   Set xlsheet2 = xlBook.Worksheets(2)


 --logic

   xlBook.SaveAs output.xls
```

(Please note: I am using Windows 7 - 64 bit system. I am using all required DLL)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Run Detect and Repair in Excel. (Alt + H, then R).

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your reply. I tried but unfortunately it did not work. The problem seems to be with writing the data to the excel sheet (2013 version).

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THIS FILE:

MSADDNDR.OLB

in commonfiles/designer

it seems that this is why in my case my vb6 programs works correctly with excel 2013

hope this helps